# Python iterating through two files by line at the same time

Tags: python, if-statement, iteration, string-matching, readlines

I am trying to compare columns in two files to see if the values match, and if there is a match I want to merge/concatenate the data for that row together. My issue is that when reading line by line from the two files separately, I can't get python to iterate through the files together and look for a match. Instead it will iterate properly through one file and iterate over the same line in the second file multiple times...

I have had this issue in the past and still not really found a way around it. I know that indentation is one problem since I mess with the loop by using "for line in a, for line in b" so I thought that what I tried below would work but it hasn't. I have looked around for solutions but nobody seems to be using the same method so I wonder if I am completely off track as to how to do this? Can anyone explain what is a better way to do this, and whether my method would work at all and if not, why not? Thanks, it is much appreciated!

These are the formats of my two files, basically I want to compare the columns filename in both files and if they match I want to merge the rows together.

```
file1:
cluster_id  hypothesis_id   filename    M1_name_offset  Orientation
1   71133076    unique_name_1.png   esc_sox2_Sox1_80_4  forward
1   50099120    unique_name_4.png   hb_cebpb_ETS1_139_7 forward
1   91895576    unique_name_11.png  he_tal1_at_AC_acptr_258_11  forward

file2:
Name                Cluster_No  Pattern     filename
esc_sox2_Sox1_80    Cluster1    AP1(1N)ETS      unique_name_4.png
hb_cebpb_ETS1_139   Cluster1    CREB(1N)ETS     unique_name_11.png
he_tal1_at_AC_acptr_258 Cluster2    ETS(-1N)ZIC     unique_name_3.png
```

What I have tried:

```
for aline in file1:
    motif1 = aline.split()[2]
    for bline in file2:
        motif2 = bline.split()[-1]
            if motif1 = motif2:
                print "match", aline, bline
```

I have also tried:

```
for aline in file1:
    motif1 = aline.split()[2]
for bline in file2:
    motif2 = bline.split()[-1]
        if motif1 = motif2:
            print "match", aline, bline
```

I have also tried using string formatting but that didn't make a difference. The first way iterates through file2 incorrectly and the second way doesn't give me any output. I have played around with it a lot and tried various indentations and extra bits but I am stumped as to how to even try and fix it! Please help me :(

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function.

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        motif1 = line1.split()[0]
        motif2 = line2.split()[0]
        ...
```

Note that `zip` behaves differently in python2 and python3. In python2, it would be more efficient to use `itertools.izip` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I print motif1 and motif2 they correctly iterate through the values in each file. However when I try to compare them with the lines below I only get one result which I know is definitely not correct. It's as if it's gone back to only iterating over one line in the second file:
    if motif1 == motif2:
        print "match"
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: it would be (marginally) slower to use `izip` ... although it would consume less memory ...

Comment: How exactly are you extracting `motif1` and `motif2`?

Comment: I'm reading in the files line by line and then splitting them to get the columns with the filename for each file

Comment: One reason I ask is that with your code as presented, you're not dealing with newline characters. `split()` will count newlines as a delimiting character, so `'foo bar\n'.split()` will return `('foo', 'bar', '')`. If you're then reverse indexing, you'll get `''` instead of a filename. Generally you either positive index and ignore the issue or use `strip()` before splitting.

Comment: Or, come to think of it, to use the `csv` module and let it worry about newlines for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Python 3. Here's a nice abstraction, `iterlines`. It hides the complexity of opening, reading, pairing, and closing *n* files. Note the use of `zip_longest`, this prevents the ends of longer files being silently discarded.

```
def iterlines(*paths, fillvalue=None, **open_kwargs):
    files = []
    try:
        for path in paths:
            files.append(open(path, **open_kwargs))
        for lines in zip_longest(*files, fillvalue=fillvalue):
            yield lines
    finally:
        for file_ in files:
            with suppress():
                file_.close()
```

**Usage**

```
for line_a, line_b in iterlines('a.txt', 'b.txt'):
    print(line_a, line_b)
```

**Complete code**

```
from contextlib import suppress
from itertools import zip_longest


def iterlines(*paths, fillvalue=None, **open_kwargs):
    files = []
    try:
        for path in paths:
            files.append(open(path, **open_kwargs))
        for lines in zip_longest(*files, fillvalue=fillvalue):
            yield lines
    finally:
        for file_ in files:
            with suppress():
                file_.close()


for lines in iterlines('a.txt', 'b.txt', 'd.txt'):
    print(lines)
```